# Skype plays beep sound every 30 seconds

Tags: windows-7, audio, skype

When Skype is turned on every 30 sec I hear the Windows beep sound.
I cant seem to find out why or how to turn it of.

I followed [this
tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-o5v1Wk9kus&feature=player_embedded)
and [this
tutorial](http://www.annoyances.org/exec/forum/winxp/t1151476956) I uncheck all the sounds like he described but I still hear a Windows beep sound every 30 sec or so even if nothing is happening in Skype.

It only happens when I have Skype running.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Edit:
I found out what it was. I have a memory card reader and somehow Skype disconnected and connected the device when active. Dont know why ??? The sounds i was hearing was the disconnect and connect sound from the memory card reader. Very strange !!! Sorry if i have wasted anyones time.

Thanks anyway. This site is awsome :D

Answer (score 2):

I found that double beep sound happening when a new contact came online.  I disabled it from the skype sound preferences